# php:publish post with images in it

Tags: wordpress, image, post, upload

I am writing a cms and I want to publish post just as wordpress.but now I am stucked!
in wordpress,if I want to publish a post with images,I should upload the image first and then I get the image path and insert into the post!
I also learn the wordpress database schema and I find there is no table for storing image information.
I just want to know how can I implement this function with php.also,I am using the ckeditor in my code!can anyone give me some ideas?
hope I describe my quetion clearly!thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but from what I understand you want a way to handle media in posts in your custom cms? Anyways first of all wordpress actually stores image(and all kinds of uploads) information in the databases and that is the purpose of the attachment post type([Codex Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Attachment)) if you want something similar to the wordpress media library for CKEditor try "JASFinder" but you'll probably have to find some kind of callback on image upload on which you'll create the meta for the image